# How to integrate function of the form $f(x)\cdot 1[\cdot]?$

Tags: calculus

How to integrate some integrable functions that are multiplied with some indicator functions?

For example,
$$\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\cdot 1[x\geq 0].$$

I have absolutely zero idea on this. I would be okay with just some hints so I can do some thinking on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a definite integral? If so, just restrict to the appropriate set and drop the indicator. For example, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cdot1_{[x\geq0]}dx =\int_^{\infty}f(x)dx $$

Comment: @MPW Does it work even if end points go to +-infinity?

Comment: Yes. Time ran out while I was editing comment before. Should be $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cdot 1_{[x\geq 0]}dx =\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx $$

Comment: @MPW Yea, I realize that when I pasted that into LaTex. Do you want to put that in the answer section? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integrand vanishes identically outside of the indicated set, its integral there is zero. What remains is the integral on the portion of the original range of integration that meets the indicated set, and the indicator is unity there.

So, for example,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cdot 1_{[x\geq0]}\;dx =\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\;dx 
$$

**Addendum:** More generally, $$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\cdot 1_{[x\in S]}\; dx = \int_S f(x)\cdot 1\; dx + \int_{\mathbb R\setminus S} f(x)\cdot 0\; dx$$
$$ =\int_S f(x)\; dx + \int_{\mathbb R\setminus S} 0\; dx$$
$$=\int_S f(x)\; dx$$